# Express radius in terms of the length of a sector and its chord

Tags: trigonometry, circles

I have a problem that asks me to find the radius of a circle. I am given **C**, denoting the length of the circumference of a sector of the circle, and **L**, denoting the distance between the two ends of the sector, the chord. I am to express **R** in terms of **C** and **L**.
I have narrowed down the eqation to,
$$ 2R \sin \left(\frac{90C}{ \pi R}\right) = L $$
But I can't seem to make **R** the subject in the equation, please help.

Comment: Let me know whether you are interested in obtaining an approximate value for $R$ using the equation mentioned in your text.

Comment: I know I can use Newton's method to find the value of R, but isn't there any way to make R the subject?

Comment: If not, please explain why I can't make it the subject.

Comment: Thanks for replying. It is possible to make $R$ the subject and express it in terms of $C$ and $L$. However, what you get is an approximate formula. Give me an hour or two to post my answer. Then you can decide whether it is appropriate or not. Ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my knowledge, the formula (1), in its original form, cannot be coerced to yield an equation, in which $R$ is the subject. But, we can concoct a method to separate $R$ from $C$ and $L$ after modifying this formula in a certain way. However, by doing so, we make the equation we derived a little less accurate.

$$L=2R\sin\left(\frac{C}{2R}\right) \tag{1}$$

Please note that we use $radians$ and not $degrees$ to measure angles. The derivation is started by expressing $\sin\left(\frac{C}{2R}\right)$ as a series. However, as shown below, we retain only the first four terms to obtain the required formula.

$$L=2R\left(\frac{C}{2R}-\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{C}{2R}\right)^3+\frac{1}{120}\left(\frac{C}{2R}\right)^5-\frac{1}{5040}\left(\frac{C}{2R}\right)^7 \right)$$

This can be written as a cubic equation of $\left(\frac{C}{R}\right)^2$.

$$\left(\frac{C}{R}\right)^6-168\left(\frac{C}{R}\right)^4+13440\left(\frac{C}{R}\right)^2-322560\left(1-\frac{L}{C}\right)=0  $$

After this equation is solved to express $\left(\frac{C}{R}\right)^2$ in terms of $C$ and $L$, we can make $R$ the subject of a formula as shown below.

$$R\approx\frac{C}{\sqrt{56-p\times\sinh\left\{\frac{1}{3}\sinh^{-1}\left[q\left(\frac{11}{45}+\frac{L}{C}\right)\right]\right\}}} \tag{2},$$

where 
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    p & = & 73.3212111192934401054087551,\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space \\
    q & = & 3.2732683535398851709761218413802. \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

The values of $R$ given by (2) are always larger than its exact value. If you want to test the accuracy of the formula (2), you can use the very-fast-converging formula (3), which is based on Newton-Raphson method, to find values of $R$ to compare with those of the former.

$$R_{n+1}=R_n\left(1-\frac{2R_n\sin\phi-L}{2R_n\sin\phi-C\cos\phi}\right),\space\space \rm{where}\space\space \mathit{\phi} =\frac{\mathit{C}}{2\mathit{R}}\space\space and \space\space \mathit{R}_0 =\frac{\mathit{L}}{2}\tag{3}$$

Instead of retaining the first four terms of the aforementioned series expansion, we could have kept the first three terms to obtain a quadratic equation in $\left(\frac{C}{R}\right)^2$, which can be used to derive another formula for $R$. The values of $R$ obtained from this formula are always smaller than its exact value and less accurate than the results of (2).